# Rewrite Rule but ignore the first directory part?

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess

It took me 2 hours but I can't figure it out and I don't know how to google a solution.

This is my Rewrite-Rule in the .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:2368/$1 [P]
```

When I call example.com/blog, it should redirect me to my blog. The blog is a ghost-blog running in nodejs (port 2368).

This would work when I use no condition. So I can see the main site of my blog at example.com.

```
http://example.com/xy => http://localhost:2368/xy
```

But with the condition and the rule, it seems like this happens:

```
http://example.com/blog/xy => http://localhost:2368/blog/xy
```

But I don't want it to redirect to http://localhost:2368/blog/xy. It sould redirect to http://localhost:2368/xy.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule you're looking for is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/(.*)
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) http://localhost:2368/$1 [P]
```

The `$1` comes from the `RewriteRule` statement, not from `RewriteCond`. So `$1` contained `blog/xy` instead of just `xy`

You can check the Rule working in here: [.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=ddcdfe06-2e94-5e57-a08c-c5c9d975b5ff)

Comment: That seems to work. But now I have this problem: The site /blog can't load css and js files correctly. A css-file is loaded from example.com/assets/built/screen.css but the correct link would be example.com/blog/assets/built/screen.css

Comment: If you have conflicts with your routes, just fix the `RewriteCond` to only redirect to Node.js where there's no file extension, or it's not an asset. And I don't understand if the `css` is located in `/assets` or `/blog/assets`

Comment: The thing is: The css file is (with your rule) reachable at /blog/assets (I can open it in the browser). But the blog wants to load /assets. That's because the blog uses absolute paths: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/built/screen.css" />.

Comment: That's a complete different issue, nothing to do wth the rule. So I recommend marking this answer as accepted, and open a new question. And I'll be happy to help you out.

Comment: Well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082902/rewrite-rule-so-that-css-and-js-files-with-absolute-paths-are-loaded-correctly

Comment: Done, answered!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189746/discussion-between-marcos-casagrande-and-alpha).