# Rewrite rule so that css and js files with absolute paths are loaded correctly

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess

It took me 2 hours but I can't figure it out and I don't know how to google a solution.

This is my Rewrite-Rule in the .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/(.*)
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) http://localhost:2368/$1 [P]
```

When I call example.com/blog, it redirects my to my ghost-blog running in nodejs (port 2368).

The problem: The blog itself loads css and js files with absolute paths:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/built/screen.css" />`.

So it tries to load example.com/assets/built/screen.css.

But the file is reachable at example.com/blog/assets/built/screen.css

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 alternatives:

- Change the links/scripts source to `/blog/assets/...`
- Change the file locations to `/assets`
- Use a `RewriteRule`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets(.*)\.(css|js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /blog/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/(.*)
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) http://localhost:2368/$1 [P]
```

Here's the rule working: [.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=8986e9a6-8c89-5a52-84f9-ef2459fa27f1)

I assume that the files are being served by apache2 and not by the `ghost-blog` running in node.js. But if it's the latter,it will still work since after redirecting it will go the next rule. But you can also do the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets(.*)\.(css|js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:2368/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok , the first two line at your rules will let every request end with css & js redirected to blog/reuest and be aware that the second rule will redirect that reuqest again to localhost:2368/reuest without bolg , so same issue

Comment: I know what my rule is doing, I even provided a tester.

Comment: This solution (and also the other one) seem like a work around for me. The first 2 alternatives are not possible because it's not my code. If I edit it and a new version comes out, I have to edit the files again. The Rewrite Rules solves 1 problem, but a new one comes up. There are a lot of links on the site that refer to /foobar. But my files are at /blog/foobar. Is this somehow solvable with `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: @Alpha didn't get the notification. Can you please provide all the routes? So I can provide you with the right solution. Is it: `/foobar.{extension}` or just `/foobar`?

Comment: @Alpha It's almost certain that whatever library/framework you're using has a setting for the app's root directory, so you don't have to mock about with rewrites or redirects. So [instead of asking about the symptom](http://xyproblem.info) you'd solve the problem faster and cleaner if you just asked "How do you change the root directory in framework XYZ?"

Comment: @JJJ What's your advice?

Comment: @Marcos Casagrade There are multiple links (all the blog posts for example). It's not possible to make RewriteRules for all of them. I think, I need something that works like the <base> html tag but more globally, so that all the links and ressource source that call /foo/... go to /blog/foo/...

Comment: I already told you my advice. Make a new question with the title "How to change the root directory in XYZ" where XYZ is the framework/library/platform that generates the links. It's impossible to tell how to "really" fix the links because you haven't told what generates them.